# How to add Japanese language into Zabbix frontend?

Tags: zabbix

I am using Zabbix for monitoring. I want to create multiple language for Zabbix frontend. How to do that?

I installed Zabbix frontend with English language as default. Now I want to add Janpanese language for frontend. I see the zabbix\locale\ja\LC_MESSAGES\frontend.po in the source code. In my Zabbix frontend, I was setting Japanese for admin account. But it didn't change to Japanese. It keep English language. I was opened the frontend.po that is correct with Japanese language.

I want to add two icons for English and Japanese languages for my Zabbix frontend. How to do that?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with Zabbix 3.4 on CentOS 7:

`# rpm -i http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-2.el7.noarch.rpm`

`# yum -y install zabbix-web-japanese`

`# yum -y install dejavu-sans-fonts vlgothic-p-fonts`

`# wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-web-japanese-3.4.15-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

`# rpm -ivh –nodeps zabbix-web-japanese-3.4.9-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

Afterwards set your user language to Japanese within the Zabbix GUI and reload page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am using xampp on window 10 to develop front-end. Could you help me how to add Japanese language on zabbix 4.0 on xampp? Thanks & Best regards,